# Align the orange box and text to the right of the image

Tags: html, css

I want the orange box (and the text) to be in line to the right of the image. I've moved around position, display and float in a few different places but I can't seem to get it in the right place. I already have a nav bar at the top of the page (which I haven't included). Not sure what else I need to say, I'm new to this...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}

/*--background image--*/

.image2 {
  position: relative;
}

.image2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 72.5%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 255, 183, 0.49653364763874297)),
    color-stop(50%, rgba(243, 255, 174, 0.4797269249496674)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(245, 225, 72, 0.5413515748096114))
  );
}

/*--right side boxes--*/

.boxes {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.boxes a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.boxes a:hover {
  color: aquamarine;
  transition: 1s;
}

.box-1 {
  color: #121212;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box-1 a {
  color: #121212;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 50px;
}

.box-2 {
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #121212;
}

.box-3 {
  color: white;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<div>
     <div class="image2"><img src="./images/PhotobyeberhardgrossgasteigerfromPexelsBW.jpg" alt="background picture2"
                width="1100">
     </div>
     <div class="boxes">
         <div class="box-1"><a href="./about.html">about</a></div>
         <div class="box-2"><a href="./portfolio.html">portfolio</a></div>
         <div class="box-3"><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I dont understand? The box is already to the right and after the image...

Comment: @ArchitGargi, it's not - divs are treated as block-level elements and the text should be positioned below it in OP's example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox), it makes it so easier. Didn't get the final layout you wanna have, but as far as aligning orange box (and the text) to the right of the image you can do it like so:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
}
/*--background image--*/

.image2 {
  position: relative;
}

.image2:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 72.5%;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 255, 183, 0.49653364763874297)),
    color-stop(50%, rgba(243, 255, 174, 0.4797269249496674)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(245, 225, 72, 0.5413515748096114))
  );
}

/*--right side boxes--*/

.boxes {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646361701353-139ad5fab84e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" >
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box-1"><a href="./about.html">about</a></div>
    <div class="box-2"><a href="./portfolio.html">portfolio</a></div>
    <div class="box-3"><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting `style="display: flex"` to your top div; flex also offers positioning at that point so you can vertically align the text in your second sub-div with `align-items`, for example `align-items: center`.

```html
<!-- <div style="display: flex; align-items: center"> -->
<div style="display: flex">
  <div class="image2"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646361701353-139ad5fab84e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHw3fHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" >
  </div>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box-1"><a href="./about.html">about</a></div>
    <div class="box-2"><a href="./portfolio.html">portfolio</a></div>
    <div class="box-3"><a href="./contact.html">contact</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```